# getting data to my fragment from my activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I finally figured out after some research how to get my `dialogfragment` to send the results to my activity, now I want to pass those results to the fragment that really is the one calling that dialog fragment (it's a date picker so I want to update the date).

I saw this here: [Call fragment events from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208377/call-fragment-events-from-activity)

The above gave me some ideas but for some reason, my fragments layout is defined in an XML and has no id with it so I cannot use the call:

```
findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentBId);
```

So I'm either defining in the xml my layout (That is my fragment) wrong, or there is another way to go about this.

My xml layout has my entire layout (all the buttons textviews linearlayouts etc) in it.  Though I never not once say `<fragment .... />`.  But I did investigate further and saw on this page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

That is how one supposed to define the fragment.  So for completeness here is my xml file that now gives me an `Error: inflating class fragment` error on the line where I define the fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <fragment android:name="com.viciousbytes.studiotab.subactivities.SessionEdit"
        android:id="@+id/session_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">  
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
      <TextView         
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text = "Client Name:" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"/>         
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/client_name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>       
</LinearLayout> 
    etc...
    etc...
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

So what am I missing? or does the id/ i refer to should point to another xml that has all this UI in it?  I am a bit confused about how it wants me to set this up.  It was working without the fragment tag but then I had no way to call:

```
SessionEdit session = (SessionEdit)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.session_fragment);
```

I just want to have my dialog date picker send info to the fragment that called it.
I had seen the dialog date picker demo but I had to change it to use the `DialogFragment` and I must of missed the "jist".

Answer (score 1):

<fragment> is not a container, it can not have any children. What you should do is have your Fragment class set its content view to what you have here as the children of the <fragment> tag. The contents you have here of <fragment> should live in its own XML file.

Comment: they did I didn't have the fragment part in there, but then didn't know how to get access to my fragment to update its views when the date was picked from the dialogfragment.  so without that fragment it had no id to grab at...so i understand that is wrong but wasnt sure how to go about it.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand your comment. The fragment tag should exist in the layout XML, it just shouldn't have children. The layout a Fragment uses should be in its own XML file. The Activity will able to findViewById() on any view in the Fragment's layout since it is attached to the Activity's view tree.

Comment: basically think i confused myself. I  have this main layout that has two fragments in it.  This sets up my layouts for my main screen a listfragment on one side and a regular fragment on the other side (displaying client details)...then my other fragments show full screens of things and I don't define any more fragments in any layouts.  I just use the layouts defined like above (without any fragment tags).  I wish I could paste a flow chart.  lol