# Which control is being used in the Date Selection of Android Calendar App

Tags: android, android-controls

I'm trying to mimic the Date Selection control of the New Event screen of the Android Calendar App. The one circled in the picture below.[image]

I already have the Dialog popping up, but what is the control that holds the date with the icon on the bottom right? Is that a built in control? If not how do I accomplish the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android spinner with date picker, like Google Calendar app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406920/android-spinner-with-date-picker-like-google-calendar-app)

Answer (score 0):

It is [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) and is available as drop down since ICS.

Refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) for implementation.

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to add it to my Activity? Designer or programmatically is fine. What attributes I need to set in order to make it popup a date picker?

Comment: Sorry, but the linked example doesn't explain how to bring up a DatePicker dialog with a Spinner.

Comment: @JonasStawski You have to custom make it. I believe you asked for the control and I told you the widget. To have datepicker you would have to customize the dropdown behavior.

Comment: this answers my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406920/android-spinner-with-date-picker-like-google-calendar-app