# How can I use a textview integrated with timepicker

Tags: android, textview, timepicker

I have to insert time, and I saw the control in the pic in:

http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

Thing is I don't know how to have a textview with an indication that you should pick it to display timepicker ( Like Section date in pic)

I could easily start a Dialog with a Timepicker inside, but what I like is the little arrow that say you can pick.

Is there any component that match that or should I use tricks to do it???

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the good response is :

```
style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.Spinner"
```

See : [Android spinner with date picker, like Google Calendar app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406920/android-spinner-with-date-picker-like-google-calendar-app)

Answer (score 1):

you can set the "style" in a textView:

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Base.Spinner"
```

and then make an intent to a time or date picker dialog, cheers.

Comment: It seems to be responded here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406920/android-spinner-with-date-picker-like-google-calendar-app