# How can I used the date picker that Google Calendar uses for my android app?

Tags: android, calendar, android-datepicker

Is there a way to use the date picker that shows up when using a DatePicker? I have implemented the DatePicker that shows the spinners for choosing the month, day and year, but the Calendar date picker would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html), just be aware that this is scrollable so it may be not a good idea to put it inside another scrollable view.

Comment: This worked, but not like I expected. I want the CalendarView to popup in its own sortof "applet," so that the user can scroll through the dates just as they do in Google Calendar when choosing the date for an event.

Comment: Put it in a AlertDialog and implement OnDateChangeListener

Comment: Is it possible to add google calender in android app

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Android spinner with date picker, like Google Calendar app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406920/android-spinner-with-date-picker-like-google-calendar-app)
or

[How to create datePicker and timePicker dialogs in fragment class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668619/how-to-create-datepicker-and-timepicker-dialogs-in-fragment-class/8127571#8127571)

You can also check this blog post..
http://www.codinguser.com/2012/06/time-and-date-inputs-in-android/