# How to create spinner wheels like the date wheel android

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have this design this Should be like the date wheel how can I do it [image: spinner]

Comment: look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406920/android-spinner-with-date-picker-like-google-calendar-app . it's not exactly what you want, but it could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Maybe you can use a [viewpager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) or a [textswitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html).
2. animate textviews 'out on top' and 'in from bottom'. Maybe use a gradient view with transparency to het the gradients ont the top and the bottom.