# Dialog from WebFragment

Tags: android

I've seen Q&A's about dialogs in fragments, for which the solution was to use a DialogFragment, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393197/show-dialog-from-fragment) for example. but I'm already compelled to be using a WebFragment - so is it impossible for me to show a dialog from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not impossible. Use an AlertDialog.Builder to display a dialog at runtime. It's very easy to use. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-to-display-alert-dialog-in-android) answer

Comment: Pass the fragment's `getActivity()` method, e.g.:

    `new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity())`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Will mark as correct as soon as SO allows me.