# DialogFragment in Class that extends from AppCompatPreferenceActivity

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, android-dialogfragment

my issue is that I have my preference activity that extends from `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` and I need to show a `DialogFragment`. So when I do the following:

```
DialogFragmente dialogFragment= new MyDialogFragmentClass()
DialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"My Dialog")
```

I get an error because I can not use the `getSupportFragmentManager()` method. So my question is how can I use that method if my class extends from AppCompatPreferenceActivity.

I tried using `getFragmentManager()` instead but it is not working neither.

this are my classes:

```
public class Settings_acticity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
    private SwitchPreference banner_switch;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private ListPreference interstial_ad;

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialog();
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "My dialog");
    }
 }
```

And the DialogFragment class:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {


    public MyDialog(){
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        View vista=getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_MyDialog,null);
        setCancelable(false);

        builder.setView(vista).setPositiveButton(R.string.aceptar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                //Yes Code
            }
        }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            //No code
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887373/calling-dialogfragment-from-fragment-not-fragmentactivity

Comment: `I get an error` show error.

Comment: The link did not solve my question. The main problem is that I need the method getSupportFragmentManager() but I can do it because of the extend AppCompatPreferenceActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you use `DialogFragment` from Support Library.

Try using the original one by importing `android.app.DialogFragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`

Then you can show the dialog with:

```
MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog();
myDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "My Dialog");
```

Comment: Thank you! It was because in my DialogFragment class I was importing the v4... So when I used android.app.DialogFragment in my Main class I got an error.