# Access Fragment in Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have one main activity with 2 fragments. Both fragments have a `ListView`. I want to update the list in `MainActivity`. Is there any way to access fragment list adapter in activity with out making adapter as static adapter.
Currently I am doing like this in `Mainactivity.java`

```
public void updatelist() {
  if(fragmentstate=0)
    Fragment1.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  else
    Fragment2.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the fragment instance from the FragmentActivity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532462/how-to-get-the-fragment-instance-from-the-fragmentactivity)

Comment: @Spity how it will be come duplicate of fragment instance.even i am using singleton in my code  for fragment.but adapter making propblem

Answer (score 5):

You could do the following with [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) event bus:

```
public class UpdateListEvent {
    private int fragmentState;

    public UpdateListEvent(int fragmentState) {
        this.fragmentState = fragmentState;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ...
    public void updatelist() {
       SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().post(new UpdateListEvent(fragmentState));
    }
}

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().unregister(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onUpdateListEvent(UpdateListEvent e) {
        if(e.getFragmentState() == 0) { //is this even necessary?
            this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().unregister(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onUpdateListEvent(UpdateListEvent e) {
        if(e.getFragmentState() != 0) { //is this even necessary?
             this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And a revised version of the Singleton Bus

```
public enum SingletonBus {
    INSTANCE;

    private static String TAG = SingletonBus.class.getSimpleName();

    private Bus bus;

    private volatile boolean paused;

    private final Vector<Object> eventQueueBuffer = new Vector<>();

    private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    private SingletonBus() {
        this.bus = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY);
    }

    public <T> void postToSameThread(final T event) {
        bus.post(event);
    }

    public <T> void postToMainThread(final T event) {
        try {
            if(paused) {
                eventQueueBuffer.add(event);
            } else {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            bus.post(event);
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "POST TO MAIN THREAD: BUS LEVEL");
                            throw e;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "POST TO MAIN THREAD: HANDLER LEVEL");
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public <T> void register(T subscriber) {
        bus.register(subscriber);
    }

    public <T> void unregister(T subscriber) {
        bus.unregister(subscriber);
    }

    public boolean isPaused() {
        return paused;
    }

    public void setPaused(boolean paused) {
        this.paused = paused;
        if(!paused) {
            Iterator<Object> eventIterator = eventQueueBuffer.iterator();
            while(eventIterator.hasNext()) {
                Object event = eventIterator.next();
                postToMainThread(event);
                eventIterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But if this is just a question of keeping track of which fragment is currently active, then this is overkill. Or at least, is the `fragmentState` even necessary? I don't think so. The fragments receive the event only if they are active, after all.

Comment: i wish i could use otto.but i can't.

Comment: Oh. That sucks. The `LocalBroadcastManager` can work as poor man's Otto.

Comment: Please note that `Otto` delivers events on the **same thread as on which you post the event**.

Comment: call `setPaused(true)` in `onPause()` and call `setPaused(false)` in `onPostCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the static adapter. There are better (safer) ways to access your fragments from it's parent `Activity`.

I'm assuming you add your fragment dynamically by using something like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager
              .beginTransaction()
              .add(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentOne())
              .commit();
```

And same for fragment two.

In order to have a reference to those `Fragment` you need to add a tag when you create them. Very simple, just add one line to your existing code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager
              .beginTransaction()
              .add(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentOne(), "fragmentOneTag")
              .commit();
```

And then whenever you want to get your fragment do this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentOne fragmentOne = fragmentManager.getFragmentByTag("fragmentOneTag");

fragmentOne.refreshList();      //Define this method in your class and from there refresh your list
```

That's it

Comment: I wonder that if `getFragmentByTag("fragmentOneTag")` will affect perfromance more than accessing adapter using `static`

Comment: `refreshList()` is not static. `getFragmentByTag` returns a reference to the requested fragment so you can access it's public methods

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to update lists on fragments, you don't have to access the adpaters. You can register local broadcast on fragments, and send local broadcast message from MainActivity.

From frgments,

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(...);
```

From MainActivity,

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).sendBroadcast(...)
```

Comment: Why would you do this? All `Fragments` must be attached to an `Activity` which has created and added the `Fragments` in the first place. All the `Activity` has to do is call a `public` method on the relevant `Fragment` reference.

Comment: @Benrad Kim you are right.everything coming into single activity.why should i broadcast?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to access fragment list adapter in activity with out making adapter as static adapter.

Yes. Design guidelines for `Fragments` allow them to expose `public` methods which can be called from the `Activity` they're attached to. Simply create a method in each `Fragment` and call whichever one you need to.

The `Activity` should be holding references to any `Fragments` it has created. Just have the `Fragment` methods update their own adapters.