# Is using event library like Otto or EventBus a recommended way to handle relations between Activities, Fragments, and background threads

Tags: android, android-asynctask, event-bus, otto, greenrobot-eventbus

In most of the case, when dealing with case

- User thread (`AsyncTask`) to perform background processing
- Pass back calculated result back to `Activity` or `Fragment`
- `Activity` or `Fragment` re-creation might happen before user thread finishes its background processing

So far, from many reliable sources, I can see the recommended way is using
**Retained Fragment**

### Sources

- [Best practice: AsyncTask during orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128670/best-practice-asynctask-during-orientation-change)
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html
- http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

From time to time, I heard event bus libraries is good for handling relations between Activities, Fragments, and background threads. (Please refer to https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus. It states that *performs well with Activities, Fragments, and background threads*)

I came across some really popular event bus libraries

- [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)
- [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto)

I was wondering, when comes to handle relations between Activities, Fragments, and background threads, how is event bus approach different from **Retained Fragment** approach?

Which ways is a recommended way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The event bus and Otto are not "recommended ways" by the Android developer guide primarily because they are **third party libraries** to simplify the task. And I believe Otto is fairly new, so older guides obviously aren't using it.

I personally like Otto, it's what I use and I haven't had any problems with it so far. But of course, that's because it suited my use-cases.

I have an example on how I used Otto [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28480952/2413303).

**EDIT from the future:** if you need an event bus, [`greenrobot/EventBus`](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) is better than Otto. Also, in some cases, [`LiveData<T>`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html) is perfectly sufficient instead of using event bus (which instead of emitting events to anyone, only emits to subscribers).

Comment: Are events received only when the fragment / activity is running?  I mean after onResume() and before onPause()?  I seem to have a case when my fragments receives a message after onPause() which is bad!

Comment: @Yar I know that feel, which is why I have an event queue here for "post to main thread": http://stackoverflow.com/a/28480952/2413303 (note: this is NOT preserved in ANY way on process death!)

Comment: So I understood it correctly: generally Otto does send events to paused fragments...

Comment: Well unless you block it, yes. Some people register/unregister in onResume and onPause, but the event would be lost. Which is why I personally allow sending events only if `paused` is `false`.

Comment: I think `EventBus` is actually better than `Otto`, now that I've used both.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I agree, the cashed(sticky) events are an invaluable feature.

Comment: Little update: Otto is decommissioned since august 2016 according to this [announcement](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/decommissioning-otto.html).

Comment: @naxa I'm talking about **this** Otto, although that has already been deprecated in favor of Rx, and EventBus3 is better anyways: https://github.com/square/otto

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering, when comes to handle relations between Activities,
>   Fragments, and background threads, how is event bus approach different
>   from Retained Fragment approach?
>
> Which ways is a recommended way?

I think you misunderstand two concepts:

1) preventing a task from creating again and again when you rotate your device

2) sending messages from a thread to an activity or from a service to a fragment or...

When we put a task inside a fragment  we just do not want to **start** it again if we are rotating. Also we want getting the result back from it for example we want to update an imageView but if you pass an imageView to an asynctask and then you rotate your device if you store the imageView as a weak reference then your imageView is null after the activity has destroyed and if you store it as a strong reference then you leak the activity. so better idea is putting it inside a fragment and storing the view as a weak reference and if the activity onCreate is called updating that reference.

EventBus and Otto are very good libraries to send messages between any components or threads. you can use those or android native solution like creating interface or localBroadcastManager or handler.

> how is event bus approach different from Retained Fragment approach?

I have not looked into source code of those but I think they created a singleton queue object and store your messages inside it and dequeue it to pass your messages to their listeners.

Comment: By using weak reference technique, you can prevent AsyncTask from calling invalid UI, but your AsyncTask don't have the ability to interact with the re-created UI. Either retained instance fragment or event bus can overcome such shortcoming.

Comment: I would rather use asynctask with LruCache so if you call it again it just deliver the result immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Communication between a simple `Activity` and `Fragment` can be easily establish in many ways but the most elegant way is by creating and using simple `interface` class. But for a scenario like **activity that host a fragment that shows another fragments using viewpager, then this child fragment needs to communicate to the parent activity or fragment**, this is where EventBus can be utilize because there will be no way you can communicate with. EventBus should only be use when there is no other way to send data to another class.

Answer (score 0):

[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) is Best as Always.

[Otto](https://github.com/square/otto) is now deprecated.

From this link of [otto](https://github.com/square/otto#deprecated):

> This project is deprecated in favor of RxJava and RxAndroid. These
>   projects permit the same event-driven programming model as Otto, but
>   they’re more capable and offer better control of threading.
>
> If you’re looking for guidance on migrating from Otto to Rx, [this post](https://blog.kaush.co/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/)
>   is a good start.