# Android - Is it correct to use Event Buses (like Otto) for UI elements communication?

Tags: android, otto, event-bus

Can I (is it correct to) use an event bus to communicate between UI views? For exemple, use it to communicate between Fragments instead of implementing a listener?

Can I use the same instance of the bus for more than one operation?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Otto was built exactly for that reason: to help you communicate `fragments` and `activities` aside without the need of serializing everything through `Intent`s.

Also, for the instance question: You can reuse the bus wherever you want to. Sometimes, though, you would prefer to create different buses to separate groups of classes communicating: for example, in an MVP architecture, you would have a bus for each M-V-P group, or in another example, a bus for communicating with a specific service that is always running, etc.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480704/access-fragment-in-activity/28480952#28480952) is a good example on how to use the library.